# How to create a book (pdf) from a website having a hierarchy of pages?

Tags: pdf, export

[This](https://walkccc.me/CLRS/) is the site containing the solutions to the classic text *"Introduction to Algorithms"* by *Cormen et. al.* I was wondering, is it possible to export the content of this website as a pdf document, so that I can keep the pdf in my pdf reader device and solving the questions on my own and check/verify the solutions without the need for internet. Is it possible? An automatic linux terminal application for instance, where I put in the website and the output shall be a well formatted pdf, (where the mathjax is formatted properly)?

Comment: Why can't you save website?  Getting a *a well formatted pdf, (where the mathjax is formatted properly)?* seems optimistic!

Comment: A simple approach would be using Acrobat Pro with the Create PDF --> from Weblink functionality.